# Get "CL_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTOR" when GLtexture GL_RED are used for clCreateFromGLTexture

Tags: opengl, opencl

I have a problem that when I use the GL_RED, GL_RED_INTEGER as the OpenGL texture format and GL_R32F/GL_R16UI as internal format, the command "**clCreateFromGLTexture**" creating the texture to OpenCL returns **CL_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTOR**. Is the format really support in OpenCL? or something is missing before using that?

the code for initialize OpenCL is briefly below:

```
void initMemoryOpenCL(bool CL_info, const size_t select_device_number,  const int device_type)
{
    cl_uint num;
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, 0, &num);
    std::vector<cl_platform_id> platforms(num);
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(num, &platforms[0], &num);

    cl_device_id *device_id = NULL;

    cl_uint num_devices = -1;
    clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[select_device_number], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 0, device_id, &num);
    device_id = (cl_device_id *)malloc(sizeof(cl_device_id)*num_devices);
    clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[select_device_number], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, num_devices, device_id, 0);

    cl_context_properties prop_cl[] = {
        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, reinterpret_cast<cl_context_properties>(platforms[select_device_number]),
        CL_WGL_HDC_KHR, (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentDC(),
        CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentContext(),
        0 };
    context_CL = clCreateContextFromType(prop_cl, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, NULL, NULL, &err);

    clGetGLContextInfoKHR_fn pclGetGLContextInfoKHR = (clGetGLContextInfoKHR_fn)
        clGetExtensionFunctionAddressForPlatform(platforms[select_device_number], "clGetGLContextInfoKHR");

    size_t bytes = 0;
    pclGetGLContextInfoKHR(prop_cl, CL_CURRENT_DEVICE_FOR_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, 0, NULL, &bytes);
    unsigned int numDevs = bytes / sizeof(cl_device_id);
    cl_device_id *devID = NULL;
    device_id = (cl_device_id*)malloc(sizeof(cl_device_id)* numDevs);
    pclGetGLContextInfoKHR(prop_cl, CL_CURRENT_DEVICE_FOR_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, bytes, device_id, NULL);

    cl_bool sup;
    size_t rsize;
    clGetDeviceInfo(device_id[0], CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT, sizeof(sup), &sup, &rsize);
    if (sup != CL_TRUE){ std::cout << "Image not Supported" << std::endl; }
    cl_uint work_item_dimens;
    size_t cb, work_group_size;

    if (checkForExtension(device_id[0],"cl_khr_gl_sharing"))
    {
        printf("Found GL Sharing Support!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Can NOT Found GL Sharing Support!\n");
    }

    this->queue_CL = clCreateCommandQueue(this->context_CL, device_id[0], 0, &err);
    this->program = load_program(context_CL, "openclfuncs.cl", device_id[0]);
}
```

Comment: Which version of OpenCL? It depends.

Comment: @thokra OpenCL is 1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section **9.7.3.1**, table **9.4** of the OpenCL **1.2 extension specification** lists the OpenCL image formats corresponding to OpenGL internal formats. Note the implementations may not support the corresponding extension, `cl_khr_gl_sharing`.

In `cl_khr_gl_sharing` for OpenCL 1.2 there is no correspondence between one- or two-channel internal formats. The spec also states that

> Texture objects created with other OpenGL internal formats may (but are
>   not guaranteed to) have a mapping to a CL image format;

I cannot speak as to why that was the case back then (ironically the D3D extensions offer a much greater wealth of formats) - it's somewhat beyond me why it needed the next CL version to get it done.

If you need support for the features you request, you're gonna have to upgrade to OpenCL 2.0 or higher - its extension specification defines the mappings you are asking for.

Alternative you could try to pack your values in a `GL_RGBA[32|16][F|UI]` texture.

---

To check whether your device supports the necessary extensions you can query t the device your operating on with function like this (C++14 required):

```
auto checkForExtension(cl_device_id device, std::string const& extensionName)
{
  std::size_t extensionSize = 0;
  clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS, 0, nullptr, &extensionSize);

  std::vector<char> extensions(extensionSize);
  clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS, extensionSize, extensions.data(), nullptr);

  auto iter = std::search(
    extensions.cbegin(), 
    extensions.cend(), 
    extensionName.cbegin(), 
    extensionName.cend()
  );

  return iter != extensions.end();
}
```

If this does not return `true` when invoked like `checkForExtension(device, "cl_khr_gl_sharing");`, then the implementation for that particular device doesn't support it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, when I use the CL 2.0  (by using the Intel HD) but the GL_R[32|16][F|UI] still not workable, any idea?

Comment: Does your implementation expose the extension `cl_khr_gl_sharing`? The kind of GL/CL interop you need is not part of the CL core spec and although the extension has the same name, the functionality differs.

Comment: @Robin: I added some code which allows you to check for a particular extension for a particular device.

Comment: @trokra I had combined the check code you give, and it return TRUE anyway when both the NV(CL1.2) or Intel(CL2.0) is chosen (by the arguement select_device_number)... my init. code is edited completely in the question, please help me to check that.. thank you!

Comment: @Robin: A conforming OpenCL 1.2 implementation offering support for `cl_khr_gl_sharing` is not required to expose a mapping to `GL_R[16|32][UI|F]` - so no surprise there. I'm a bit puzzled that the Intel implementation reports that the extension is supported but it still wont work. Please share the GL code setting up the texture and code CL which tries to create a CL image from the GL texture.

Comment: @trokra very very sorry for reply late... finally I find the other way to solve the problem, by choice the depth_component here. Many thanks for your patient on my issue.